# How to continue in loop on first GREP result

Tags: shell, loops, while-loop, grep, do-while

I have this following .sh file which searchs for tons of search items in tons of files. But I want to continue the while loop at first result if one of the search items is present in $file. Currently, it is so that a query is matched in all files. The first hit is enough.

How can I do this?

```
while read file
do
    echo $file
    grep -o -f searchItems.txt "$file" >> results.txt
done < filelist.txt
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `break` after a successful `grep` return:

```
while read -r key; do
   while read -r actualFile; do
     echo "searching for $key in $actualFile"
     grep -o "$key" "$actualFile" >> messageKeysInUse.txt && break
   done < filelist.txt
done < allMessageKeysFromDB.txt
```

It will break out of inner while loop as soon as a `grep` succeeds.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not working. I have just 4 hits after 31 seconds. I'm expecting about 900.

Comment: Thanks. But I think I have to switch the while-loops because my results.txt have a lot of equal hits.

Comment: I'm searching for a key in any file. If a key is present in any file, I want to search after the next key in all files until I found it the first time.

Comment: The script was still running this morning and I saw about 20 entries with the same word in results.txt.

Comment: I'm testing this now: while read -r key; do
 while read -r actualFile; do
  echo "searching for $key in $actualFile"
  grep -o "$key" "$actualFile" >> messageKeysInUse.txt && break
 done < filelist.txt
done < allMessageKeysFromDB.txt

Comment: ok update answer with that. So isn't this working for you now? Inner while will break when `grep` is successful and outer while will iterate to next key.